# Describe if statement. Write an if statement to multiply even numbers by 3 and odd numbers by 4

Tags: if-statement

Describe if statement. Write an if statement to multiply even numbers by 3 and odd numbers by 4.

Comment: Please show us what you have done first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two way to do if condition in java.
Java Code:

STEP 1:

```
 System.out.println(number%2==0?number*3:number*4);
```

STEP 2:

```
 if(number % 2==0)
    System.out.println(number*3);
 else
    System.out.println(number*4);
```

both are same function.

Answer (score 0):

Python code

```
if number % 2 == 0:
    print number * 3
else:
    print number * 4
```